The number of qubits of the ansatz does not match the operator
I am trying to run my below code on FakeSherbrooke() system, but I am getting an error as shown below:
The number of qubits of the ansatz does not match the operator, and the ansatz does not allow setting the number of qubits using num_qubits.
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit import Aer
import numpy as np
from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator

from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeSherbrooke
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE
# backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
# backend = AerSimulator()
backend = FakeSherbrooke()
Hamiltonian = [
    [ 4.07981221, -3.6713615 ,  1.3943662 , -1.05164319],
    [-3.6713615 ,  5.88262911, -4.14084507,  1.37558685],
    [ 1.3943662 , -4.14084507,  5.83098592, -3.54929577],
    [-1.05164319,  1.37558685, -3.54929577,  3.79812207]
]
H_op = MatrixOp(Hamiltonian).to_pauli_op()
ansatz = EfficientSU2(num_qubits=2,
                    entanglement= 'linear',
                    reps= 5,
                    skip_final_rotation_layer= True)
ansatz_opt = transpile(circuits=ansatz,
                            backend = backend,
                            optimization_level =3)
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter= 1500)
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend= backend,
                                        shots= 1024,     # default is 1024   # changing the number of shots to 32M
                                        seed_simulator= 28,    ##
                                        seed_transpiler= 28,
                                        basis_gates= None,
                                        optimization_level=2)

initial_point_values = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(ansatz_opt.num_parameters)
vqe = VQE(ansatz=ansatz_opt,
        optimizer= optimizer,
        quantum_instance=quantum_instance,
        initial_point=initial_point_values
        )

result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op)
print(result)

Really not sure why I am getting this error and how to resolve it. This code is using qiskit== 0.46.
I also tested the qiskit==1.0 version of the above code and I still get this error.
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager

from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

import numpy as np

from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2

from qiskit_algorithms import VQE
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA

from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as Estimator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import  FakeSherbrooke

backend = AerSimulator()
# backend = FakeSherbrooke()

Hamiltonian = [
    [ 4.07981221, -3.6713615 ,  1.3943662 , -1.05164319],
    [-3.6713615 ,  5.88262911, -4.14084507,  1.37558685],
    [ 1.3943662 , -4.14084507,  5.83098592, -3.54929577],
    [-1.05164319,  1.37558685, -3.54929577,  3.79812207]
]

H_op = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(Hamiltonian)

ansatz = EfficientSU2(num_qubits=2,
                    entanglement= 'linear',
                    reps= 5,
                    skip_final_rotation_layer= True)

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(
    optimization_level=3,
    backend=backend,
    basis_gates=None,
    seed_transpiler=28
)
ansatz_opt = pm.run(ansatz)

optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter= 1500)

estimator = Estimator(
    run_options = {"shots": 1024, "seed": 28},
)

initial_point_values = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(ansatz_opt.num_parameters)

vqe = VQE(
    estimator=estimator,
    ansatz=ansatz_opt,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    initial_point=initial_point_values
)

result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op)
print(result)

Any way to correct this error?

The problem is that when transpiling your ansatz to use the FakeSherbrooke backend, it goes from 2 qubits to 127.
You must first apply the ansatz's layout to the Hamiltonian before passing it to VQE:
H_op = H_op.apply_layout(ansatz_opt.layout)

And then everything runs smoothly using the 1.0 version of your code.

Thank you for the help @TristanNemoz. What is the substitute of H_op = H_op.apply_layout(ansatz_opt.layout) in qiskit == 0.46?

@Manu The apply_layout method already existed in 0.46.3, so it should still work. I said it worked with the 1.x version of your code because it's the only one I tested. If you have difficulty doing something in 1.x that you could do in 0.46.3, feel free to ask a question about it! Otherwise there's no real reason to use 0.46.3 anymore anyway (or at least, not that I can think of).

Thank you for the help @TristanNemoz.
